# How can I create charm on one node

Tags: installation, juju, qt, nodejs, berkeleydb

Firstly I generation nodejs file on the node without charm then my boss said we need charm for generation. I need  in this charm  QT5, NODEjs, Berkeley db, g++ with gcc but I don't know how create charm because I`m a beginner in juju charm...and I need result in end to the next week

Answer (score 1):

In the install hook for the charm, you can apt-get install all your dependencies or manually install them (Up to you).

Here is an example of an install hook from another charm:

- http://jujucharms.com/charms/precise/mediawiki/hooks/install

Here is the documentation for writing a charm, this is a step by step guide on how to get started:

- https://jujucharms.com/docs/stable/developer-getting-started